# Imprimir radio checado no UlkitCSS

Tags: css

Uso o UlkitCss e tenho trechos de um formulário com campos input radio conforme abaixo.

Ao imprimir (Ctrl+p ou  window.print() ou $windows.print) o campo não aparece checado. O radio selecionado simplesmente não aparece.
Como fazer para aparecer o campo checado na impressao?

Tenho um código:

```
 <form>
                <div class="uk-margin padding">
                    <div class="uk-form-controls">
                        <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4">item 1.</label><br>
                        <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4"> item 2</label><br>
                        <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4" checked="checked" ng-checked="true">item 3</label><br>
                        <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4">item 4 </label>


                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Você precisa criar um [exemplo verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para demonstrar o problema, só esse pedaço de código não ajuda. Veja que coloquei esse código no fiddle e o print funciona perfeitamente no Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/528256/

Comment: Com o seu código do jeito que está na pergunta executado em uma página sem esse UIKit e sem o angular está funcionando normal, quando eu aperto Ctrl+p ele aparece checado, então é algo no CSS ou mais provavelmente no angular que esta tirando o checked na hora de imprimir a página

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Israel não entendi muito bem a maneira que você utilizou o **ng-checked**, você ainda o usou junto com o **checked** do *HTML*, assim provavelmente não funciona. O mais indicado aí seria como no exemplo que fiz, utilizando `model` e setando um **value** nos *inputs*. Aí o que você setar no model refletira no input, aí é só mandar imprimir:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.marcado = 3;     // marca o terceiro checkbox
});

/* função de impressão */
document.getElementById('imprimir').onclick = function(){
  window.print();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div class="uk-margin padding">
          <div class="uk-form-controls">
              <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4" ng-model="marcado" value="1">item 1.</label><br>
              <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4" ng-model="marcado" value="2"> item 2</label><br>
              <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4" ng-model="marcado" value="3">item 3</label><br>
              <label><input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="item4" ng-model="marcado" value="4">item 4 </label>

          </div>
     </div>
</form>

<button id="imprimir">Imprimir</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Identifiquei onde o problema acontece. Não se tratava do angularjs nem do jquery.
No arquivo do CSS do UlkitCSS, linha 1606 a 1627 existem as propriedades:

```
  .uk-radio,
.uk-checkbox {
  /* 1 */
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  /* 2 */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* 3 */
  margin-top: -4px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 4 */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* 5 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 6 */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition-property: background-color, border;
}
```

Bastava comentar o trecho

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
```

e agora aparece o radio/checkbox selecionado na impressao